# Repast: how to get a particular agent set based on multiple conditions?

Tags: repast-simphony

There is an answer about how to get the desired agent set with only one condition:
[Repast: how to get a particular agent set based on the specific conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351812/repast-how-to-get-a-particular-agent-set-based-on-the-specific-conditions)

How does such thing work for multiple conditions? (e.g. ask rich_people with [wealth > 100000 and age <= 50 and sex = male])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compose Queries with the AndQuery and the OrQuery. See,

https://repast.github.io/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/query/AndQuery.html

Comment: AndQery only return an iterable over the objects in the intersection of the "two" queries. What if there is more than two conditions to consider?